# Probability Measures and Cardinality > c

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, pr.probability

Is it possible to place non-trivial probability measures on sets of cardinality strictly greater than the continuum -- in particular, on sets of cardinality 2^c?  (Any references would be appreciated.)

Comment: Yes, of course. You can always give $2^X$ the product measure. A decent reference is volume 2 ("Broad foundations") of Fremlin's treatise on Measure theory. Look at Section 254 (Infinite products). (The book may be available online from Fremlin's page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's even more. If your set can be considered as a product of probability spaces, its measure will have some good properties. This is a theorem due to Alexandra Ionescu Tulcea: given an infinite (with arbitrary cardinality) family of probability spaces
$$\left\{(\Omega_n, \mathscr{B}_n, \mu_n)\right\}_{n \in I}$$
if we call
$$\pi_m : \prod_{n \in I} \Omega_n \rightarrow \Omega_m$$
the canonical projection, then it's possible to give $\Omega \mathrel{\mathop{:}=} \prod_{n \in I} \Omega_n$ the structure of a probability space with measurable sets
$$\mathscr{B} = \bigotimes_{n \in I} \mathscr{B}_n$$
and probability measure $\mu : \mathscr{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\forall \{n_1, \ldots, n_t\} \subset I \ \ \forall (A_{n_1}, \ldots, A_{n_t}) \in \prod_{i = 1}^t \mathscr{B}_{n_i}$$
$$\mu\left(\pi_{n_1}^{-1}(A_{n_1}) \cap \ldots \cap \pi_{n_t}^{-1}(A_{n_t})\right) = \mu_{i_1}(A_{i_1}) \ldots \mu_{i_t}(A_{i_t})$$

Comment: Isn't this just a special case of Kolmogorov's Consistency Theorem?

Comment: That result is not due to Ionescu Tulcea, it is older than that, see [Notes on infinite product measure spaces, I](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195573633) by Kakutani, 1943.